# Make DIV extend in height to bottom of parent DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV which appears in a parent dive bellow some text in it. I want the div to extend to the bottom of the parent div. The parent div is repeated multiple times and has varying amounts of text, so the top starting position of the kid div changes.

I can't find any sort of way to simply make a dive extent auto down until it hits the parent, also being able to do a:

```
margin: 70%;
```

but have this only apply to the top of the parent div as opposed to the text within would also work great.

This fiddle is a good example of where I'd want DIV 1c to extent to the bottom of DIV1 so if I were to alter the heights of any of the other DIVs it would auto adjust. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGaG/5/

Full html for article and DIVs associated with the area in question:

```
<article class="bookcover">
                        <div class="info">


                            <h2>'.$row->BookName.'</h2>                  
                            <p class="authors"><b>Written By:</b> ';while ($Authors = mysql_fetch_object($Aresult)){echo $Authors->Forename.' '.$Authors->Surname.', ';}echo"<br><b>Release Year: </b>".$row->PublishDate = substr($row->PublishDate, 0, -6).'<br>
                            <b>Genre:</b> '     ;while ($Genres = mysql_fetch_object($Gresult)){echo $Genres->Genre.', ';}echo"".'</p></footer>

                            <div id="Plot'.$row->BookID.'">
                                <table>                                                
                                <tr><td>'.$row->Plot.'</td></tr>                                    
                                </table>

                            </div>

                            <div class="detailsContainer">

                                <a href="javascript:unhide(\'BookDetails'.$row->BookID.'\');">
                                <div class="detailview"><b>Book Details<br></a></div>

                                        <div id="BookDetails'.$row->BookID.'" class="hidden">
                                            <table>
                                            <tr><td>Total Stock </td><td>'.$row->TotalStock.'</td>
                                            <td>Current Stock</td><td>'.$row->CurrentStock.'</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Awards </td><td>'.$row->Awards.'</td>
                                            <td>Film</td><td>'.$row->Film.'</td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div> 

                        ';?>


                                <br><center><a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
                                onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
                                <div class= "obutton feature2">Reserve Book</div></a></center>                                
                                <div id="light2" class="white_content"></div>
                                <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>                 
                            </div>
                    </div>


                        <?php echo '<div class="image">
                            <img src='.$row->BookCover.'>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

CSS:

```
.bookcover {
    width: 30%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.info {
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    margin:5%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0.92);
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
    opacity:0;
}
.bookcover .image {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:5%;
}
.bookcover:hover .info{
    opacity:1;
}

.authors 
{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.detailsContainer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.detailview
{
    width: 30%;
    height: 29px;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.obutton
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
    background:rgba(204,204,204,0);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: @Diodeus It doesn't look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Diodeus 100% doesn't work here as that just makes the child DIV the full height of the parent, for some reason it doesn't scale the 100% size of the left distance between where the text ends and parent div ends. I don't understand how 100% could be thought to be relevant, when I say there is stuff in the div already above it.

Comment: if it is only a matter of background, then let last div transparent and give its' background property to .div1 , see http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have static heights on the parent and 1a and 1b. This means you could use the min-height preoperty:

```
.div1 {
    background: wheat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
}
.div1a {
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
.div1b {
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
}
.div1c {   
    background: pink;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq9zy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also , default height and overflow are auto so make these changes.. [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGaG/28/)

```
.div1 {
background: wheat;
width: 150px;
height: 300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.div1a {
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}
.div1b {
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
.div1c {   
height:inherit;    
background: pink;  
}
```

Comment: When I try it on my actual site, it just pushes the button I have on the bottom of the div out of view, off the overflow of the div, and I don't know why

Comment: can you provide html and css of this button issue..?

Comment: This fiddle s what I have, but it doesn't show anything and I don't know why on there, but should help I think. http://jsfiddle.net/vereonix/dHLRc/

Comment: Ah, so it works perfectly there, but on my site is inherits the parents full height and goes over the edge:  http://i.imgur.com/3eiDjhi.png

Comment: sorry its not very clear .. but is .info class have the same css position : absolute .. etc and what is parent tag article with .bookcover class css ?

Comment: .info is absolute which is a div which is made visible over the div .cover which is position: relative. Sorry for the messed up pc, point was it shows that the .info div is massive and taking full height of parent div, and not just reaching bottom an stopping like in the jsfiddle.

Comment: when u give ht/wd in % its in parent space if .info div is inheriting wd/ht from parent tag that might effecting it and also make sure every div have close tag that's also effect the css. I can't help u until u give me html to inspect.

Comment: Its hard to debug as i am not getting content (php code stuff ..) but 1 small suggestion if its help .. remove overflow: hidden; from .bookcover class. and opacity:0; fron .info class css.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42908/discussion-between-neha-and-tom)